# Why can't people distinguish Sailor Soldiers from their real selves?

Tags: sailor-moon

When people transform in Sailor Moon, they look physically identical to their human forms.  Even fellow magical beings are unable to tell a person's identity unless they witness the transformation happening.

Is there an in-universe explanation for this?

Comment: I just watched EP 3 of Sailor Moon Crystal. Rei (sp?) [Sailor Mars] recognized Sailor Moon as Usagi from the bus.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a [common trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ClarkKenting) in a lot of super hero fiction. It's just one of those things that creators ask audiences to suspend disbelief for. Though it's not really meant as an explanation, many characters do poke fun at various scouts' [paper-thin disguises](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PaperThinDisguise) in universe, saying things to the effect of "She can't be Sailor Moon; Sailor Moon is too pretty to be that meatball head." (It must be the tiara.)

Comment: I hadn't noticed the mentions before.  Good find!

Answer (score 9):

Although it is a **common trope** these days, it was **not so in the genre of *mahou shoujo*** (magical girl) manga and anime **before *Sailor Moon***. In the long-running genre, many of the classic magical girls **looked very different in their transformed state as compared to their civilian state** (for example, [Maho no Mako-chan](http://www.toei-anim.co.jp/lineup/tv/mako/), [Creamy Mami](http://shoujo.tripod.com/creamymami.html), [Mahou no Yousei Persia](http://shoujo.tripod.com/pelsia.html), [Magical Emi](http://shoujo.tripod.com/emi.html), [Fashion Lala](http://shoujo.tripod.com/lala.html), etc.). *Sailor Moon* largely helped set a new standard that caught on in the genre (though there are still series which use the older classic style of very different looks for civilian vs. transformed forms, such as [Pretty Cure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Cure) does).

Judging by the mangaka Takeuchi Naoko's [early concept art](http://gallery.missdream.org/albums/scanlation_smoon/smoon_materialscollection/materials002.png) for the [character designs](http://gallery.missdream.org/albums/scanlation_smoon/smoon_materialscollection/materials003.png), she had **not intended them to look obviously identical** in both forms. All of the sailor soldiers **wore a mask** of some sort so that, like Tuxedo Kamen, they would be hard to identify by enemies and bystanders. The early published artwork also featured [a mask](http://gallery.missdream.org/albums/raws/japanese/smoon_kanzenban/volume%201/005.jpg) for [Sailor Moon] in [the style](http://gallery.missdream.org/albums/raws/japanese/smoon_kanzenban/volume%201/031.jpg) of [Sailor V's](http://gallery.missdream.org/albums/raws/japanese/sailorv/sailorv_raw_shin1/034.jpg).

In the concept art, Sailor Moon was drawn with pink hair and Sailor Jupiter with olive-green hair; this may or may not have been the same shade as their civilian hair color: it would have matched the magical girl standard for Usagi's hair to change from her civilian white (platinum blonde) or blonde hair color into a different shade, such as pink (the most common and symbolic color for magical girls).

In terms of an in-universe explanation for the phenomenon, one is not given, *but* it *is* demonstrated that while people do not generally recognize them, there is not some magic that flatly prevents it, as there are **some occasions in which someone does recognize a person who is transformed**.  In episode 183, Sailor Star Fighter looks at Sailor Moon and suddenly an image of Usagi flashes through her mind; she quickly shakes it off, saying that's impossible (she doesn't want to admit it because it is easier for her personally if Sailor Moon and Usagi are different people, so she willfully ignores what she noticed). As another example, in episode 190 Sailors Uranus, Neptune, and Pluto intentionally transform in front of Taiki Kou and Yaten Kou because they are sure that Taiki and Yaten are Sailor Star Maker and Sailor Star Healer, respectively.  Neptune asks, "So you aren't easily surprised, are you?" and is answered with "We anticipated it, somehow."

In *Sailor Moon Crystal*, **recognition seems to be easier** than in the classic anime. Tuxedo Kamen seems to have no trouble identifying Usagi as the same person as Sailor Moon whenever she is transformed into her various guises using her Hensou Pen (Transformation Pen). When Rei sees Sailor Moon in episode 3, she quickly realizes it's Usagi. We could chalk these up to Rei's intuition or soldier abilities and Mamoru's powers, but even Usagi's father is able to notice her when she is in a transformed form in episode 4.  She walks past him at a party in her transformed form and he does a double-take, thinking he saw his daughter, and only subsequently concludes that he must have made a mistake.

Comment: I like answers that at least consider the in-universe perspective, they way they do over at SFF.SE, rather than just saying "It's a lame trope of the genre", so +1 from me.

Comment: +1 Nicely written and well documented. As an aside, the image you identified as Sailor V actually has her introducing herself as Sailor Venus. Her appearance is similar to the end result for Sailor V, but this is in keeping with the concept art you showed earlier where all the senshi wore masks.

Comment: @Paul Rowe, you're right that she introduces herself as 「セーラーヴィーナス」(Sailor Venus) in this page, but it is a [page](https://missdream.org/raw-sailor-moon-downloads/codename-sailor-v-shinsobon-edition/codename-wa-sailor-v-shinsoubon-volume-1/) from chapter 1 of the _Codename ha Sailor V_ manga. That series is a prequel to _Sailor Moon_ but it was written partly concurrently.

Comment: FWIW in ch. 3 of the manga, Usagi notices that Mamoru looks like Tuxedo Mask when she's talking to him on the bus too.

Answer (score 0):

But there are a lot of people that recognizes her.

In the manga, Usagi and Mamoru recognizes each other just after they Knows each other. In the anime, maybe the 1992 anime's Usagui are too stupid to notice it, (In the 1992 Anime, Mamoru Himself don't know that he was Tuxedo Kamen until the appear of Sailor Venus).

The Senshi tries to don't show herselves directly on public, But Naru Osaka Suspect that Usagi was Sailor Moon, Rei Hino Recognizes her at the bus, most of the enemies know her civilian forms.

At that proof, the Sailor Moon's Transformation do not have the power to make the people that forgot the User's Face or something like that.